# Does Minecraft have an API?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm now sure if this is the correct place for this question (or something like StackOverflow) but I'll ask it here first in any case. Does Minecraft have an API for obtaining information about it's craftable items?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you looking for a way to discover recipes while playing, or are you looking for an API you can use while developing a mod?

Comment: Neither. I wanted to pull this information using something like Ruby, Javascript, PHP, etc

Comment: Aha! That's entirely different, yes. I'm not sure this is on topic, but I'm not sure it's off topic either.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you're going to downvote at least give a reason...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no API that exposes in-game recipes to an external program. It would be feasible to write a mod that created such an interface, though I don't believe any such mod exists yet. That would require users to install a mod in order to use the external tool though, which would make such a tool useless to the majority of players with a "vanilla" (unmodded) version of Minecraft.

Comment: There is a server plugin probably also installable as a mod that creates the command /recipe

Answer (score -1):

The API you speak of is under development. See

. Here, Jeb, Dinnerbone, EvilSeph and Grum talk about the future of the Minecraft Mod API.

Currently, Minecraft Forge and ModLoader (as well as smaller APIs like LiteLoader) exist to fill the spot. Texture packs becoming resource packs and singleplayer becoming an internal server are changes towards the new API.